# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnimationView'

Tags: swift, uikit, lottie

What does this mean?

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnimationView'

been struggling to figure out what i means and how to fix it?
any help would be appreciative

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            
    if let animationView = AnimationView(name: "breathing") {
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
        animationView.center = self.view.center
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        view.addSubview(animationView)
    
        animationView.play()
    }
```

Comment: [More than 150 similar Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Initializer+for+conditional+binding+must+have+Optional+type) and none of them helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear `AnimationView(name: "breathing")` isn't an optional.

Replace:

```
if let animationView = AnimationView(name: "breathing") {
```

With:

```
let animationView = AnimationView(name: "breathing")
```

Comment: just tried this and it worked for a while, then error to say
Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'AnimationCacheProvider?' that does not accept a closure

Comment: @libbywinfield Avoid the curly braces at the beginning and the end.